# Linq с sqlite. Современные методы работы

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq

Не нашел ни одного нового способа для работы linq и sqlite. Одни советы с устаревшими или неподдерживаемыми инструментами. Если не ошибаюсь, от 2015 года.
Какой способ используется сейчас? Сам новичек в c#. Пользовался python.

Comment: EFCore, наверное, сейчас должен нормально работать с sqlite, там и есть основной подход — Linq

Comment: Берёте любую LINQ-ORM и используете. Всё. / Стандартом де-факто является Entity Framework Core (новейшая версия: 7). Лично от себя рекомендую LINQ to DB.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну как любую, например в EF6 с sqlite не работал Code First. Так что нюансы могут быть